# How do i parse Json data from openlibrary api? (properly)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Forgive me if this has been answered. I have seen various answer regarding json data and openlibrary

So far the json data I am getting from openlibrary and the json data i see used in examples seem to differ in the format

My question is, Using php (or javascript) how do i get the data into an array or indavidual variables and put them into a mysql database.

- addition to previous question -
  I would like to display the raw data below as:

Title: Tile of book
Author: Author of book
Isbn: Isbn number
etc.

and then put these details into a mysql data base

[Update 2015-011-07] Now I have recieved the answer, I have updated the code below to show how it should be.
The following will request json data from openlibrary and it will be returned as a string. the ISBN number in $url is just for testing purposes, so by all means change it.

```
<?php
$url ="https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0789721813&jscmd=details&format=json";

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: \"run\""
); 

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($cURL);

foreach (json_decode($result, true) as $book) 
 {
   printf("\nISBN: %s\ttitle: %s\tauthor: %s", $book['details']['isbn_10'][0], $book['details']['title'], $book['details']['contributions'][0]);
 }

curl_close($cURL);
?>
```

When the page is loaded the following is displayed:

```
ISBN: 0789721813 title: Red Hat Linux author: Hellums, Duane
```

Comment: have you tried `json_decode($result, true)` ? what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: Ther response that you copied has multiple lines; so that could be a reason that the parsing is not working

Comment: What I would like is to get the isbn, author publisher etc from the raw data and save the appropriate values to a database or screen

Comment: Profligate.fcx, I think that's my doing  I'll edit it and make sure it's displayed as is

Comment: Jeff I tried Jain_decide and the output is the same, what I would like is to change how it is displayed on the page and ultimately save it in mysql

Comment: You might want to include the code with which you tried to parse the JSON, the way you are accessing the parse results and the failure or difference between what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: try doing json_decode(json_encode($result, true));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `cURL` automatically output the transfer. Your code only displays the json content, but `curl_exec($cURL)` returns 1 or 0 if something gets wrong, and not the json content. That's why you are unable to get the array or object you want with `json_decode`, the JSON string is not in the `$result` variable.

To obtain what you want, you need to set an other cURL option:

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

In this way `curl_exec($cURL)` will return the transfer as a string and will no more output it automatically.

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) about the returned values of `curl_exec`.

Then you only need to use `json_decode`:

```
foreach (json_decode($result, true) as $book) {
    printf("\nISBN: %s\ttitle: %s\tauthor: %s", $book['details']['isbn_10'][0], $book['details']['title'], $book['details']['contributions'][0]);
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you very much
I have read the page you linked to on php.net but it would have taken me a good while to get to this for loop.  Thank you Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: I have a funny one for you Casimir et Hippolyte
I put this through:
https://openlibrary.org/api/books.json?bibkeys=ISBN:4893583565&jscmd=details

and there was no:
"contributions": ["Authors name"],

But instead:  
"authors": [{"name": "Chieko Kan\u014d", "key": "/authors/OL6522097A"}]

I tried: 
$book['details']['authors'][0]
$book['details']['authors']
$book['authors']['name'][0]

sadly Chieko Kan didn't appear, any ideas ho i can tackle this perticular area?

Comment: @benjayhutton: first, you must use this url format: https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:4893583565&jscmd=details&format=json . In the previous example there was no `authors` items, that's why I used the first item of `contributions`. Now if you look carefully the array, you will see that the "first" author name has this path (use `print_r` to see it): `$book['details']['authors'][0]['name']`

Comment: I think I'm beginning of to understand the syntax now thank you I'll try it

Answer (score 1):

this will maybe help

```
echo 'title : '.$book['details']['title'].'<br />';
echo 'subtitle : '.$book['details']['subtitle'].'<br />';
echo 'lc_classifications : '.$book['details']['lc_classifications'][0].'<br />';
echo 'latest_revision : '.$book['details']['latest_revision'].'<br />';
echo 'edition_name : '.$book['details']['edition_name'].'<br />';
echo 'languages : '.$book['details']['languages'][0]['key'].'<br />';
echo 'subjects : '.$book['details']['subjects'][0].'<br />';
echo 'location : '.$book['details']['location'][0].'<br />';
echo 'type : '.$book['details']['type']['key'].'<br />';
echo 'publish_country : '.$book['details']['publish_country'].'<br />';
echo 'other_titles : '.$book['details']['other_titles'][0].'<br />';
echo 'publishers : '.$book['details']['publishers'][0].'<br />';
echo 'last_modified : '.$book['details']['last_modified']['value'].'<br />';
echo 'key : '.$book['details']['key'].'<br />';
echo 'authors : '.$book['details']['authors'][0]['name'].'<br />';
echo 'publish_places : '.$book['details']['publish_places'][0].'<br />';
echo 'pagination : '.$book['details']['pagination'].'<br />';
echo 'works : '.$book['details']['works'][0]['key'].'<br />';
echo 'isbn 10 : '.$book['details']['isbn_10'][0].'<br />';
```

Comment: Looks right to me. Mine is slightly different but only in terms of how the text is presented on screen 