# How do i parse Json data from Wikia api? in this case yugioh.wikia.com

Tags: php, json

I asked a similar question here: [How do i parse Json data from openlibrary api? (properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351849/how-do-i-parse-json-data-from-openlibrary-api-properly)

However it seems the code i got from there dosent appear to be able to parse the json from Wikia.com. I have looked at the api and I have managed to obtain some Json and so far I have managed to do the following:

```
<?php

    $url = "http://yugioh.wikia.com/api/v1/Search/List/?query=stardust&limit=25&namespaces=0%2C14&format=json";
    $headers = array( "Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",  "Accept: text/xml", "Cache-Control: no-cache",           "Pragma: no-cache",             "SOAPAction: \"run\""         ); 
    $cURL = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($cURL);

    var_dump($result);
    foreach (json_decode($result, true) as $book) 
        {
            printf("\nId: %s\tTitle: %s\tUrl: %s", $book['items']['id'][0], $book['items']['title'], $book['items']['url']);

            switch (json_last_error()) 
            {
            case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                echo ' - No errors<br><br>';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded<br><br>';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch<br><br>';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                echo ' - Unexpected control character found<br><br>';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON<br><br>';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded<br><br>';
            break;
            default:
                echo ' - Unknown error<br><br>';
            break;
            }

        }

?>
```

I have used var_dump($results) to see whats coming through before i get to the foreach loop:

```
string(3325) "{"total":2670,"batches":107,"currentBatch":1,"next":26,"items":[{"id":79895,"title":"Stardust Dragon","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Dragon","ns":0,"quality":99},{"id":245281,"title":"Stardust Shimmer","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Shimmer","ns":0,"quality":91},{"id":197443,"title":"Stardust (disambiguation)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_(disambiguation)","ns":0,"quality":16},{"id":461985,"title":"Stardust (archetype)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_(archetype)","ns":0,"quality":68},{"id":202487,"title":"Stardust Mirage","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Mirage","ns":0,"quality":84},{"id":157331,"title":"Stardust Overdrive","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Overdrive","ns":0,"quality":98},{"id":310759,"title":"Stardust Battle","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Battle","ns":0,"quality":82},{"id":319208,"title":"Stardust Overdrive Plus","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Overdrive_Plus","ns":0,"quality":92},{"id":161435,"title":"Stardust Xiaolong","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Xiaolong","ns":0,"quality":95},{"id":237946,"title":"Stardust Phantom","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Phantom","ns":0,"quality":95},{"id":486075,"title":"Stardust Warrior","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Warrior","ns":0,"quality":94},{"id":476844,"title":"Stardust Re-Spark","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Re-Spark","ns":0,"quality":94},{"id":163366,"title":"Stardust Flash","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Flash","ns":0,"quality":93},{"id":231866,"title":"Stardust Divinity","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Divinity","ns":0,"quality":87},{"id":400288,"title":"Token (Stardust Spark Dragon)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Token_(Stardust_Spark_Dragon)","ns":0,"quality":86},{"id":317827,"title":"Stardust Spark Dragon","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Spark_Dragon","ns":0,"quality":92},{"id":156235,"title":"Ensure Stardust Dragon's return","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Ensure_Stardust_Dragon%27s_return","ns":0,"quality":45},{"id":132165,"title":"Stardust Dragon\/Assault Mode","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Dragon\/Assault_Mode","ns":0,"quality":98},{"id":196680,"title":"Malefic Stardust Dragon","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Malefic_Stardust_Dragon","ns":0,"quality":97},{"id":216824,"title":"Stardust Dragon (character)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Dragon_(character)","ns":0,"quality":96},{"id":259230,"title":"Malefic Stardust Dragon (character)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Malefic_Stardust_Dragon_(character)","ns":0,"quality":92},{"id":516389,"title":"Stardust Charge Warrior","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Charge_Warrior","ns":0,"quality":84},{"id":469151,"title":"Stardust Dragon (Duel Arena)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Dragon_(Duel_Arena)","ns":0,"quality":97},{"id":493911,"title":"Stardust Spark Dragon (manga)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Spark_Dragon_(manga)","ns":0,"quality":89},{"id":494358,"title":"Stardust Dragon (anime)","url":"http:\/\/yugioh.wikia.com\/wiki\/Stardust_Dragon_(anime)","ns":0,"quality":95}]}"
```

Sadly the only output i get when i load the page is

[-The String from the Var_dump above-] Id: Title: Url: - No errors

Id: Title: Url: - No errors

Id: Title: Url: - No errors

Id: Title: Url: - No errors

Id: Title: Url: - No errors

I have tried:

```
...
printf("\nId: %s\tTitle: %s\tUrl: %s", $book['items']['id'], $book['items']['title'], $book['items']['url']);
...
```

Comment: how you get data card info and not all publications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the properties of the json object. It contains

```
"total":2670,
"batches":107,
"currentBatch":1,
"next":26,
"items":[...]
```

Your code is looping through each of those properties instead of the items array. Your print statement is also accessing the incorrect indexes.

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);

foreach ($json['items'] as $book) 
{
    printf("\nId: %s\tTitle: %s\tUrl: %s", $book['id'], $book['title'], $book['url']);
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0f9ed981148cd5a2abaa5b5ce0a6292cca5740c

Comment: Thanks for taking me to school lol I am new to json and this and the last answer i got from my other question certinly helps a lot ^_^